# Did Orchestra evolve into MAAS?

Tags: maas, orchestra

I never knew what Orchestra really was, I'd like to ask, [MAAS](http://maas.ubuntu.com) is orchestra with another name?, if not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAAS is the next evolution of Orchestra, based on past experiences and development on Orchestra.

> It lets you provision your servers dynamically, just like cloud instances – only in this case, they’re whole physical nodes. “Add another node to the Hadoop cluster, and make sure it has at least 16GB RAM” is as easy as asking for it.
>
> With a simple web interface, you can add, commission, update and recycle your servers at will. As your needs change, you can respond rapidly, by adding new nodes and dynamically re-deploying them between services. When the time comes, nodes can be retired for use outside the MAAS.